# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError A camera app

Tags: java, android, camera

I have an issue/ problem, i've been searching for a couple of weeks and still no solution.
this app is for taking a photo with a frame inside it. the frame is in PNG.

When I start the app everythong goes great, but when I click the button to take a picture the app crashes . sometimes it give OutOfMemoryError and sometimes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException so I tried almost everything and yet nothing.
should I change the size of the drawbles? or should I set the size of the final bmp ?

I'm sorry for my English since I'm french..
here is the code

```
private class CapturePictureCallback implements PictureCallback {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Bitmap picBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 10,
                data.length);

        final ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.main_flipper);
        View flipperView = flipper.getCurrentView();

        Bitmap flipperBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(flipperView.getWidth(), flipperView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas flipperCanvas = new Canvas(flipperBitmap);
        flipperView.draw(flipperCanvas);
        Bitmap resizedFlipperBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(flipperBitmap, 500, 300, true);

        // Insert image on top
        Bitmap overlaidBitmap = overlay(picBitmap, resizedFlipperBitmap);

        picBitmap.recycle();
        resizedFlipperBitmap.recycle();

        // Create file
        save(overlaidBitmap);
        overlaidBitmap.recycle();
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap( 0,0, bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }


    private void save(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File picturesFolder = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1) {
            picturesFolder = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
        } else {
            picturesFolder = Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        }

        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);
        String fileName = "kissthepresident" + dateString + ".jpeg";
        File pictureFile = new File(picturesFolder, fileName);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
            bitmap.recycle();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);

                values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
                values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateString);
                values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
                values.put(Images.Media.DATA,
                        pictureFile.toString());
                values.put(Images.Media.SIZE, pictureFile.length());

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
                getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            } else {
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        new String[] { pictureFile.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.main_layout));
    System.gc();
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof View) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

and here is the catlog

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:403)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:418)
at com.kissthepresidents.Main$CapturePictureCallback.onPictureTaken(Main.java:255)
at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:529)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Have you got some idea what may be causing the OutOfMemoryError? Surprising how so many people think that users at StackOverflow love debugging someone else's code for free.

Answer (score 1):

**One problem:** decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length)

```
Bitmap picBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 10,
            data.length);
```

Should be (I don't know what your offset of 10 is about, but you should correct the length).

```
Bitmap picBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 10,
            data.length - 10);
```

Comment: actually when i put 0, i get the memory error, and when i put 10 i get the other one..